# Road Graph in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, analysis

I am learning transport related analysis in QGIS. While using Road Graph (Shortest Path), after giving the specifications, the shortest path panel is not being displayed.

[image]

[image]

Could some one help?

Answer (score 2):

The panel is named 'shortest path'.  You can activate it under view > panels > shortest path.
[image]